# Passing multiple values to AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having some problem when trying to pass a String and object to AsyncTask class. So when my button on click, it should pass in a String and an EventReview object into the AsyncTask class:

```
viewDtlEventBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            new GetEventDetailAsyncTask(new GetEventDetailAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                public void onFinish() {
                    //Get the values returned from AsyncTask and pass it to another activity
                }
            }).execute(String.valueOf(eventIDTV.getText()));
        }
    });
```

And inside my AsyncTask class, I am getting String as the parameter:

```
public static class GetEventDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {
    EventController eventCtrl = new EventController();
    Context context;

    public interface OnRoutineFinished { // interface
        void onFinish();
    }

    private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;

    public GetEventDetailAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback) { 
        mCallbacks = callback;
    }

    public GetEventDetailAsyncTask() {
    } // empty constructor to maintain compatibility

    public GetEventDetailAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            eventCommentModel = eventCtrl.getEventCommentByID(params[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
        if (mCallbacks != null)
            mCallbacks.onFinish(); // call interface on finish

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }
}
```

So I wonder is there any possible way to pass in a String and EventReview object to the execute() and then when doInBackground(), each execute each method. Any guides?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass String and your custom class' object in `Object[]` in asynctask.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[2];
obj[0] = "my data";
obj[1] = myEventReviewObj;
new GetEventDetailAsyncTask().execute(obj);
```

AsyncTask:

```
public static class GetEventDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Double> {


    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String paramStr = "";
    EventReview eventReview = null;
        if(params[0] instanceof String && params[1] instanceof EventReview) {
            paramStr = (String) params[0];
            eventReview = (EventReview) params[1];
        }
        else {
            eventReview = params[0];
            paramStr = params[1];
        }

        try {
            //perform operation using String and Object as per your need
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution works and it's very clear to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Create custom constructor and save the passed variables in your AsyncTask:

```
public static class GetEventDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {
    EventReview eventReview;
    private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;
    String string;
    Context context;

    public GetEventDetailAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback, String str, EventReview review) { 
        mCallbacks = callback;
        string = str;
        eventReview = review;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then call the AsyncTask by passing your vars:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    new GetEventDetailAsyncTask(
            new GetEventDetailAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                public void onFinish() {
                    // Get the values returned from AsyncTask and pass it to another activity
                }
            },
            String.valueOf(eventIDTV.getText(),
            eventReview).execute());
}
```

Comment: So by using this, when I call the AsyncTask, do I still need to call the onFinish()? Because I have to pass the values returned to another activity

Comment: @IWasSoLost your question is  unclear. You didn't say anything about returning any of these values.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I've updated the question already. But with your constructor, how should I get the string and object to do different task in doInBackground()?

Comment: @IWasSoLost I still don't understand what you mean. You can access both the `string` and the `eventReview` in the `doInBackground`, because after the constructor is called they are a part of your AsyncTask class.

Comment: Sorry my bad again. But with your codes, the CallBack when you call the AsyncTask is giving me an error message about Callback unresolved to a type. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @IWasSoLost You need to replace that to what ever the callback was. I think in your example it was a click listener.

Comment: But how should I modify it? Because I am kinda lost :(

Comment: @IWasSoLost well if you're lost to the level that you can't explain what you want, I'm not sure how we are supposed to answer your question :) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class to accept `Object`s as input:

```
public static class GetEventDetailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Double>
```

and check if the object is an instance of `String` or of `EventReview`

```
 @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if(params[0] instanceof String) // it is String
        else if(params[0] instanceof EventReview) // it is EventReview
    }
```

Comment: Change the class to accept Object? But where is the Object?

Comment: @Mohamed_AdbAllah If I changed to this I am getting error message as The method getEventCommentByID(String) in the type EventController is not applicable for the arguments (Object).

Comment: you need to cast it as a String if(params[0] instanceof String) eventCommentModel = eventCtrl.getEventCommentByID((String) params[0]);